# How to generate the JSON format data progarmatically using javascript or jquery whatever is good

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

suppose there is gridivew and every row has three textbox for employee name, employee age and employee department name. there are 10 rows or could be more. so user can enter 10 employee data. i will use PageMethod which will accept that will accept the employee info which i will send from client side.

so when user will enter many employee record and click submit button then how can i generate json format data and send to server side function. can any one like to show it with the help of code snippet. basically i need to send complex data from client side to server side method. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a fairly complex object using forms and jQuery's `.serializeArray()` function. Here is a quick link to it in the API.

http://jqapi.com/#p=serializeArray